# How to store images in android?

Tags: android, xamarin

I am trying to develop an app on android using xamarin.
i just wanted to know where to store images.I mean which way is better, should i store images in DB or in a separate folder. 
which one is better?

I was talking about images of products. for example:- i downloaded the ebay app today. app is very small in terms of size. but ebay has loads of images of the products.

Please explain.

Comment: Are you talking about image Assets (such as logos and such)?

Comment: @Sachin you need to clarify whether you want to store images at run time or images that are bundled with the app

Comment: I was talking about images of products.
for example:- i downloaded the ebay app today. app is very small in terms of size. but ebay has loads of images of the products.

Answer (score 2):

Store your files in the folder name returned by this:

```
  Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)
```

It will return the local folder of your app in internal storage:

```
/data/data/@PACKAGE_NAME@/files
```

Answer (score 0):

Store them in Resource folders (build action AndroidResource) as described [in the Xamarin.Droid docs](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_1_-_android_resource_basics/).

Make different sizes of your image for different screen-densities and store them in seperate folders as described [in the Android developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html#create-bitmaps).